# Comment dit-on « snuff movie » en français ?

Tags: terminologie

Après quelques recherches le terme *snuff* viandrait de *to snuff out* = **mourir** en anglais ([source](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snuff_movie)). N'étant pas convaincu de la traduction j'aimerais en savoir plus sur le terme le plus approprié en français pour décrire ce genre de film.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de l'origine du terme tu ferais mieux de poser la question sur [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) car c'est vraiment une question d'anglais et c'est pour ça que je réponds en commentaire car cette partie de la question n'a pas sa place ici. Le verbe *snuff* en argot veut dire « tuer ». Au départ il y a le nom *snuff* qui est la mèche de la bougie, de là on a fait le verbe *snuff (out)* qui veut dire « éteindre une bougie ». Puis en argot on est passé de la bougie à la personne. On appelle snuff movie un film où on voit des gens se faire tuer sans effets spéciaux.

Comment: Ok merci pour ces précisions.

Comment: To *snuff out* does **not** mean *mourrir* (to die). It means *tuer* (or *faire mourrir*). The reference cited is simply wrong on this score.

Answer (score 2):

*[snuff](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/snuff) movie* (film de meurtre ou torture réels) est conservé en français, tout comme d'autres termes cinématographiques : *[thriller](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/thriller)* (film de suspense à frissons), *[western](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/western)* (film de l'ouest américain), *[bukkake](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bukkake)* (film d'éjaculations collectives sur autrui).